# The seed entity for entity type 'Animal' cannot be added because there was no value provided for the required property 'Id'.'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

When I run my project it keeps throwing this error. The database exists and everything should work fine. Does anyone know what is my mistake?

The error happens in EnsureCreated / EnsureDeleted.

Error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The seed entity for entity type 'Animal' cannot be added because there was no value provided for the required property 'Id'.'

Code:

```
public class Animal
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Picture { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Category")]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}

public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        string connectionString = "Server=(localdb)\\AnimalShopProject;Database=PetShop;Trusted_Connection=true";
        services.AddDbContext<AnimalContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
    }
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, AnimalContext ctx)
    {
        ctx.Database.EnsureDeleted();
        ctx.Database.EnsureCreated();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute("Default", "{controller=AnimalShop}/{action=Index}");
        });
    }
}
public class AnimalContext : DbContext
{
    public AnimalContext(DbContextOptions<AnimalContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Animal> Animals { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Animal>().HasData(          

        #region AddingAquatics
        new Animal
        {
            Id = 1,
            Name = "Shark",
            Age = 5,
            CategoryId = 1,
            Picture = "images/shark.jpg",
            Description = ""
        },...
```

Comment: What it means  },.... Could you pls show the whole code for animall

Comment: If you don't provide a primary key value, the `IMigrationsModelDiffer` wouldn't know that the records are the same..

Answer (score 0):

You have a foreign key public int CategoryId { get; set; }. I think you have to start from Category since it looks like table Category doesn't have for example Id=1 for the first Animal record.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Category>().HasData(    

new Category{
CategoryId=1,
Name=.......
} 
);     

       
 modelBuilder.Entity<Animal>().HasData(          

           new Animal
        {
            Id = 1,
            Name = "Shark",
            Age = 5,
            CategoryId = 1,
            Picture = "images/shark.jpg",
            Description = ""
        },...
```